# Oracle Cast and MULTISET avaliable in POSTGRES

Tags: oracle, postgresql, casting, multiset

I have been working on a query to generate xml from the oracle database database

where "column" is a type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "column" AS OBJECT
                  ("coulmnname" VARCHAR2 (30), "datatype" VARCHAR2 (30))
```

and col_list_t  is of type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE col_list_t AS TABLE OF "column"
```

and

```
  SELECT CAST (
                      MULTISET (
                           SELECT "column" (B.COLUMN_NAME, B.DATA_TYPE)
                             FROM all_tab_columns b, all_tables c ,all_tables a
                            WHERE     b.TABLE_NAME = a.TABLE_NAME
                                  AND b.table_name = c.TABLE_NAME
                                  AND B.OWNER = C.OWNER
                                  AND c.OWNER = USER)AS col_list_t)  from dual
```

and problem is that this has to be converted into postgres as CAST and MULTISET are not avaliable in postgres so is there any way around to do this in postgres syntax

Comment: `cast(...)` *is* available in Postgres, but `multiset` is not. If you are generating XML, did you look at the various XML functions in Postgres?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't really support the SQL standard `MULTISET` operator, nor nested sets in general. You could create an `ARRAY` of `ROW` types like this:

```
select array[row(1, 2), row(3, 4)]
```

And you could even unnest the above array

```
select * from unnest(array[row(1, 2), row(3, 4)]) t(a int, b int)
```

So, if an `ARRAY` of `ROW` is acceptable to you, you could write something like this:

```
select array_agg(row(a, b))
from (
  select ...
) t(a, b)
```

If you have your own `OBJECT` type in PostgreSQL, you can cast the anonymous `ROW` to your type:

```
select array_agg(row(a, b)::your_type)
from (
  select ...
) t(a, b)
```

Comment: I'm always a little shocked when there's a useful SQL-standard way of doing something that Oracle supports and PostgreSQL doesn't. Oracle not being known for its love of doing things the standard way. At a quick glance, multisets look exceedingly useful.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I'm very surprised myself. Of course, much of the SQL standard has been driven by Oracle and IBM in the past, so often, it's not really surprising to find Oracle features in there - e.g. also ordered aggregate functions via `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ...)`. In this case, Oracle doesn't fully implement the standard, but requires the OP's `CAST` to a named collection type. In the standard, collections and arrays can be anonymous as well, as implemented by Informix, for example

Comment: @CraigRinger: Another point for Oracle vs. PostgreSQL: `MERGE`

Comment: Yeah, MERGE is ... well, a mixed bag. It's a great OLAP data merging tool, but it often gets incorrectly abused for OLTP UPSERT-style use, where it's just plain broken. It doesn't replace proper upserts.

Comment: @CraigRinger: It depends on the database. In theory, there's no such thing as abuse :-)

Comment: What about nowdays? Did anything change? I could not find any significant changes on the internet unfortunately.

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: Nope